# org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client-api always including com.squareup.okio 1.6.0 version

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, okio

We have a CVE reported `CVE-2023-3635` which requires the package `com.squareup.okio_okio` to be upgraded to 3.4.0.
I have explicitly pinned this version in pom.xml
ex:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
                <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.6</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
                        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
                        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
            </dependency>
```

`mvn dependency tree` shows 3.4.0 however when I extract the jar I see okio 1.6.0 is still included.

```
META-INF/maven/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client-api/pom.xml:                    <!-- okio declares a top level package instead of nested -->
META-INF/maven/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client-api/pom.xml:                      <pattern>okio/</pattern>
META-INF/maven/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client-api/pom.xml:                      <shadedPattern>${shaded.dependency.prefix}.okio.</shadedPattern>
META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties:groupId=com.squareup.okio
META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties:artifactId=okio

cat META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okio/okio/pom.properties
#Generated by Maven
#Tue Aug 25 19:59:48 EDT 2015
version=1.6.0
groupId=com.squareup.okio
artifactId=okio
```

How do I avoid including this 1.6.0 version and always pick up latest 3.4.0?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `hadoop-client` is not the same as `hadoop-client-api`. Also, if something is shaded, I dont think exclusions apply